# How to convert a date format to a UNIX Timestamp?

Tags: date, unix, time, lua, epoch

I am trying to convert a date (let's say 5/08/2022), then I want to check if it's past the current date.

So, for example: I am making a system where it will check if an expiration date is past the current date. If so the boolean will be true.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I am fairly new to Lua programming.

```
-- Check Hunting License --
QBCore.Functions.CreateCallback('hidden-hunting:server:getLicenseStatus', function(source, cb)
    local src = source
    local Player = QBCore.Functions.GetPlayer(src)
    local licenseTable = Player.PlayerData.metadata["licences"]
    local licenseItem = Player.Functions.GetItemByName("huntinglicense")
    local isExpire = false  
    
    local timeToConvert = licenseTable.huntingexp
    
    print("Time from Huntingexp: "..timeToConvert)
    
    local m, d, y = string.match(timeToConvert, "([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)")

    local convertedTimestamp = os.time({month = m, day = d, year = y})
    
    print("Converted from String: "..convertedTimestamp)
    print("Current: "..os.time())
    
    local daysfrom = os.difftime(os.time(), convertedTimestamp) / (24 * 60 * 60) -- seconds in a day
    local wholedays = math.floor(daysfrom)
    
    print("Days? "..wholedays)

    local current = os.time()

    if current > convertedTimestamp then
        print("AH?")
        isExpired = true
    end
    
    cb(licenseTable.hunting, licenseItem, isExpired)
end)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what's wrong with your code. What input do you use? What output or error do you get? What would you want to get instead?

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using QBCore for FiveM.

```
local currentTime = os.time() * 1000
local m, d, y = string.match("05/08/2022", "([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)")
local convertedTimestamp = os.time({month = m, day = d, year = y}) * 1000

if (currentTime > convertedTimestamp) then
   print("Expired")
else
   print("Not expired")
end
```

The above code converts the current datetime and the license datetime to UNIX (since `os.time()` returns the current time in **seconds** and not **milliseconds**) and compares them.

Comment: I actually solved this, I was overcomplicating it! Thank you!